# Cleanest way to select items from Richfaces table? Picklist?

Tags: user-interface, datatable, richfaces

I'm looking at ways to select items from a Richfaces table. In the past I have worked with checkboxes. They make one heck of a mess and are tough to maintain. The picklist is the exact type of functionality I want, but the user will be picking/selecting based on a number of factors so a dataTable (or extendedDataTable) makes sense.

**What is the cleanest way to select items from a Richfaces table?** 
*If your answer is picklist, please elaborate on how to merge the table and picklist functionality.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rich:extendedDataTable` has an attribute [`selection`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/extendedDataTable.html) to bind to a variable in the MBean that holds your selected rows.This variable should be in the type of `org.richfaces.model.selection.Selection`

Your  `rich:extendedDataTable` should also allow you to select multiple lines ,which can be done by  specifying the `selectioMode` attribute to be `multi`

So , you `rich:extendedDataTable` should probably likes :

```
<rich:extendedDataTable  value="#{mBean.custList}"  selection="#{mBean.selection}" selectionMode="multi" >
```

In your the Mbean , you can access the selected rows from the `mBean.selection` variable:

```
public class Mbean {

         //List to be displayed to the rich:extendedDataTable 
           private List<Customer> custList ;


         //Variable to hold the selected row
           private SimpleSelection selection;

         /*
           Getter and setter of the custList  and selection
         */

         public void someMethod(){

           //Code snippets to access the selected rows
           Iterator<Object> iterator = this.selection.getKeys();
           while (iterator.hasNext()){
             Integer key = (Integer) iterator.next();
             Customer cust = (Customer) this.custList.get(key);
             System.out.println(cust.toString());
           }


         }


}
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I'd never known the depth of the selection tags!